# Bounded harmonic function on $\mathbb{R}^3$

Tags: real-analysis, harmonic-functions

Any suggestions how to get started? I know Liouville's theorem, but not sure how to apply it here:

> Let $u$ be a harmonic function on $\mathbb{R}^3$. Assume there exists $C>0$, independent of $x$, such that $$|u(x)| \leq C(1+|x|)$$ on $\mathbb{R}^3$. Show that then $\partial_i u$ is constant on $\mathbb{R}^3$, $\forall i = 1,2,3$

Comment: If you know Liouville's theorem then you only need to show that $\partial_jf$ is bounded. Somewhere in the book there's an inequality giving bounds on derivatives of harmonic functions in terms of bounds on the functiion...

Comment: Do you know the Poisson representation on a sphere?

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich I don't know what book you mean?

Comment: @TrialAndError No don't know what that is.

Comment: Do you know that the value of a harmonic function at the center of a sphere is the average value of the function on surface of the sphere?

Comment: @TrialAndError Yes, I know the mean value property, if that is what you mean

Comment: No modified representations other than mean value?

Comment: I was referring to whatever source you learned Liouville from. You know that L theorem is a generaliztion of the L theorem in complex analysis, right? There exist theorems for harmonic functions in $\Bbb R^n$ that are similarly analogous to "Cauchy's Estimates" in complex...

Comment: No, are they difficult to prove? Do I need them? @TrialAndError

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Ah ok, no we proved Liouville using just real analysis.

Comment: Right. I didn't mean to suggest that you used complex in proving Liouville. I suspect that the _proof_ of Liouville that was given used certain inequalities that can also be used here. But never mind, just realized that the mean-value property is enough...

Comment: The Poisson representation is too much to prove, and would not be expecte of you for this problem. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_kernel

Comment: @TrialAndError Turns out it follows just from the mean-value property if you look at it right, no Poisson integral needed. Say the answer I posted...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, balls versus spheres: The ball with center at the origin and radius $r$ is $$B_r=\{x\,:\,|x|<r\},$$as opposed to the sphere of radius $r$, defined by $|x|=r$.

We know that harmonic functions satisfy the mean-value property in the sense that $u(x)$ is the average of $u$ over a sphere centered at $x$. If you integrate in "polar coordinates" you get a mean-value property for *balls*:

$$u(x)=\frac{c}{r^3}\int_{x+B_r}u.$$Here $x+A=\{x+y\,:\,y\in A\}$, so that $x+B_r$ is the ball of radius $r$ centered at $x$.

Given two sets $A$ and $B$, the *symmetric difference* is $$A\Delta B=(A\setminus B)\cup(B\setminus A).$$That is, $A\Delta B$ is the set of points in one of the sets but not both.

Now say $x\in\Bbb R^3$ and take $r>|x|$. To be on the safe side say $r>2(1+|x|)$. Now $$u(0)-u(x)=\int_{B_r}u-\int_{x+B_r}u$$. So $$|u(x)-u(0)|\le\frac c{r^3}\int_{B_r\Delta(x+B_r)}|u|\le\frac c{r^3}M_{r+|x|}m(B_r\Delta(x+B_r)),$$where $m(S)$ is the volume of $S$ and $M_r$ is the supremum of $|u(y)|$ for $|y|\le r$.

The hypothesis on $u$ shows that $M_{|x|+r}\le 1+|x|+r$. If $r$ is large enough this shows $$M_{|x|+r}\le 2r.$$

Now note that $x+B_r\subset B_{|x|+r}$. Hence $$(x+B_r)\setminus B_r\subset B_{|x|+r}\setminus B_r.$$ That's a spherical shell with radius $|x|+r$ and thickness $|x|$, so again if $r$ is much larger than $x$ we get $$m((x+B_r)\setminus B_r)\le cr^2|x|$$(note the standard convention in analysis: the value of "$c$" cah change from line to line...) Similarly for the other half of $B_r\Delta(x+B_r)$, so $$m((x+B_r)\Delta B_r)\le cr^2|x|.$$

Put all these inequalities together and divide by $|x|$ and you get $$\frac{|u(0)-u(x)|}{|x|}\le c.$$This shows that $$|\partial_ju(0)|\le c.$$

The same argument gives the same bound at every other point. So the partials of $u$ are bounded, hence constant.

(If you work out the details it may look like you get a different bound at other points. Let $r\to\infty$.)

Comment: That looks right. Very nice!

Comment: @TrialAndError How much you want to bet that the proof of Liouville he says he saw proceeded along more or less the same lines?

Comment: Great, thanks. I'll need some time to understand everything, but I think I can take it from here.

Comment: Ahh! That makes sense. Almost forgot to +1 you guys.

Comment: Yes you are right it does look similar, sorry I probably could have got there myself, but I didn't think the exercise would be this difficult. Thanks again.

Comment: @john I didn't mean it that way - was just acknowledging that it was really the same as something I'd done before...